# Searching versus Filtering in Restful API

Tags: rest, api, restful-architecture, api-design

I have started reading some references about API design (Amazon, Microsoft, Github, Apigee..) and I encountered this sentence:

> "A better API must implement search and filter functionality."
>   (something like that ..)

I did not figure out:

**What's the difference between Filtering and Searching in Restful context?**

Cordially

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Searching is all about the **query** that is being passed by the API consumer. Something like passing a **`?q=rafael`** on a user context to find all users matching that name. Filtering, on the other hand, is about **narrowing down** those results based on **other attributes** from the resource. Something like **`?q=rafael&age=23`**.

Answer (score 0):

May be its too late to answer this question but search is bit different then filter. Filter is used to narrow down result set with exact match while the search uses its weight.
For example if I want to find user in India then we can use country filter and narrow down the result set. But at the same time I want to see how many Rafael in this result set. 
Search may response with Rafaela, rafaelb or Rafael but filter will remain exact country Indaa not Indiaa or Indiab.

This is basic difference between two.